# How i can separate a sentence in php?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a sentence with `[1234]-blablabla` and i want to keep only the number `1234`. Could someone tell how could I achieve this thing?

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? Have you looked at regular expression matching? What is the exact format of the sentence?

Comment: @Karmen did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$str = '[1234]-blablabla';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($matches); // print as an array
$new_string = $matches[0][0]; // assign to an string variable

echo $new_string; // print that string variable.
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/7ano0t

Note:- it's up to you how you want. Array or string. I putted both for your convenience. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $str = '[1234]-blablabla';
    preg_match_all('([\d]+)', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
array(2
0   =>  1234
1   =>  1234
)
```

Check here 
http://www.phpliveregex.com/